# how to find the error part in java coding

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem where java.29 error.

can anyone help me tell where is my java error?

```
/MyClass.java:27: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
```

1 error

Comment: You need to show us your code if you want us to find errors in it.

Comment: The closing curly bracket for the class MyClasss.java is missing. Add a curly bracket at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at your error and read it slowly it will start making sense

`/MyClass.java` This shows in which class the error is coming from.
`:27` This shows the line on which the error is. 
`: error: reached end of file while parsing}` this is the actual error.
 Basically what its saying is that it can't find `}` on line 27 so if you have this for example, java is expecting

```
public class MyClass{
...
}
```

But, yours looks something like this instead

```
public class MyClass{
...
```

Go to `MyClass` and on line 27, you will see what's going on. 
This is a compilation error